# R caper package: reading in phylogeny error

Tags: r, warnings, phylogeny

I'm fairly new to R and I'm trying Phylogenetic Generalised Least Squares (PGLS) for the first time, using the addon package 'caper'. My phylogeny consists of 125 species. I'm getting an error when I read in the phylogeny that I created in Mesquite software (saved as a Nexus file):

```
##reading in my phylogeny

reptilephylogeny <- read.nexus ("reptile_phylogeny_new_edit.nex", tree.names = NULL)

##it gives me the following warning message:

Warning message:
In matrix(x, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) :
 data length [253] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [127]

##So I checked how R is treating the tip labels:

reptilephylogeny$tip.label  

  [1] "Apalone_spinifera"          "Staurotypus_triporcatus"   
  [3] "Gehyra_variegata"           "Egernia_whitii"            
  [5] "Ameiva_erythrocephala"      "Lacerta_vivipara"          
  [7] "Lacerta_agilis"             "Podarcis_muralis"          
  [9] "Podarcis_sicula"            "Psammodromus_algirus"      
  [11] "Tropidurus_itambere"        "Tropidurus_torquatus"      
  [13] "Cyclura_nubila"             "Ctenosaura_bakeri"         
  [15] "Uta_stansburiana"           "Sceloporus_graciosus"      
  [17] "Sceloporus_scalaris"        "Sceloporus_jarrovi"        
  [19] "19"                         "20"                        
  [21] "21"                         "22"                        
  [23] "23"                         "24"                        
  [25] "25"                         "26"                        
  [27] "27"                         "28"                        
  [29] "29"                         "30"                        
  [31] "31"                         "32"                        
  [33] "33"                         "34"                        
  [35] "35"                         "36"                        
  [37] "37"                         "38"                        
  [39] "39"                         "40"                        
  [41] "41"                         "42"                        
  [43] "43"                         "44"                        
  [45] "45"                         "46"                        
  [47] "47"                         "48"                        
  [49] "49"                         "50"                        
  [51] "51"                         ""                          
  [53] "Basiliscus_vittatus"        "Emoia_atrocostata"         
  [55] "Lygosoma_laterale"          "Tropidurus_albemarlensis"  
  [57] "Tropidurus_semitaeniatus"   "Varanus_bengalensis"       
  [59] "Intellagama_lesueurii"      "Alligator_mississippiensis"
  [61] "Caiman_latirostris"         "Caiman_crocodilus"         
  [63] "Caiman_yacare"              "Caretta_caretta"           
  [65] "Carettochelys_insculpta"    "Chelodina_longicollis"     
  [67] "Chelonia_mydas"             "Chelydra_serpentina"       
  [69] "Chrysemys_dorsalis"         "Chrysemys_picta"           
  [71] "Clemmys_guttata"            "Crocodylus_acutus"         
  [73] "Crocodylus_moreletii"       "Crocodylus_johnstoni"      
  [75] "Crocodylus_niloticus"       "Crocodylus_porosus"        
  [77] "Crocodylus_palustris"       "Crotalus_horridus"         
  [79] "Cuora_flavomarginata"       "Deirochelys_reticularia"   
  [81] "Dermatemys_mawii"           "Emydoidea_blandingii"      
  [83] "Emydura_macquarii"          "Emys_orbicularis"          
  [85] "Eretmochelys_imbricata"     "Gopherus_agassizii"        
  [87] "Gopherus_berlandieri"       "n86"                       
  [89] "n87"                        "n88"                       
  [91] "n89"                        "n90"                       
  [93] "n91"                        "n92"                       
  [95] "n93"                        "n94"                       
  [97] "n95"                        "n96"                       
  [99] "n97"                        "n98"                       
 [101] "n99"                        "n100"                      
 [103] "n101"                       "n102"                      
 [105] "n103"                       "n104"                      
 [107] "n105"                       "n106"                      
 [109] "n107"                       "n108"                      
 [111] "n109"                       "n110"                      
 [113] "n111"                       "n112"                      
 [115] "n113"                       "n114"                      
 [117] "n115"                       "n116"                      
 [119] "n117"                       "n118"                      
 [121] "n119"                       "n120"                      
 [123] "n121"                       "n122"                      
 [125] "n123"                       "n124"                      
 [127] "1"
```

It seems as though R isn't filling the data rows/columns consistently - in my species list, there are no gaps between each species, yet clearly here R thinks there are spaces (in this case numbers) between the species names. Does anyone have an idea of why this might be happening?

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: Please post the phylogeny itself (paste from the text file) or a link to the nexus file so that people can replicate your error.

Comment: You most likely have an error in the nexus file. As @Slowloris said, we cannot solve this without your data. For example, tip 52 seems to be missing. Check semicolons in your nexus file.

Comment: Apologies for not answering. I used a different approach, and read in a 'phy' format phylogeny, using the 'read.tree' function and this seemed to solve my problem.